# Checking if a class is a subclass of another

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

I want to check if a class is a subclass of another without creating an instance. I have a class that receives as a parameter a class name, and as a part of the validation process, I want to check if it's of a specific class family (to prevent security issues and such). Any good way of doing this?

Comment: The way this is written is confusing, the question is actually for a way to determine if one class is a sub-class of another.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`is_subclass_of()`](http://php.net/is_subclass_of) will correctly check if a class *extends* another class, but will not return `true` if the two parameters are the same (`is_subclass_of('Foo', 'Foo')` will be `false`).

A simple equality check will add the functionality you require.

```
function is_class_a($a, $b)
{
    return $a == $b || is_subclass_of($a, $b);
}
```

Comment: is_a() works with instances of objects, and not the names of the classes themselves.

Comment: This doesn't work with relatively namespaced classes. For example ```is_class_a('stdClass','\stdClass')``` will return FALSE even though they are one and the same.

Comment: Use `instanceof` as per @sirlancelot's answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/782741/467386

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`is_a()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) with the third parameter `$allow_string` that has been added in PHP 5.3.9. It allows a string as first parameter which is treated as class name:

#### Example:

```
interface I {}
class A {}
class B {}
class C extends A implements I {}

var_dump(
    is_a('C', 'C', true),
    is_a('C', 'I', true),
    is_a('C', 'A', true),
    is_a('C', 'B', true)
);
```

#### Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/pGBkf

Answer (score 16):

Check out [`is_subclass_of()`](http://php.net/is_subclass_of). As of PHP5, it accepts both parameters as strings.

You can also use [`instanceof`](http://php.net/instanceof), It will return true if the class *or* any of its descendants matches.

Answer (score 15):

Yup, with [Reflection](http://us.php.net/oop5.reflection)

```
<?php

class a{}

class b extends a{}

$r = new ReflectionClass( 'b' );

echo "class b "
    , (( $r->isSubclassOf( new ReflectionClass( 'a' ) ) ) ? "is" : "is not")
    , " a subclass of a";
```