# Possible to check if a class is extended in php?

Tags: php, inheritance

Is it possible to see if a class has been extended or if a class has a parent? The reason I ask is because if I want to see if a method has been overwritten in a class who has a parent, and then return that parent class name.

So:

```
class A{
  public function method(){ ... }
}

class B extends A{
  public function method(){ ... }
}
```

`method()` has been defined and then overwritten in `class B`. Is there some reflection or method or something in php I can do to say, "oh the function your calling? ya its in a class who has a parent, the parent's name is `A`"

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but check out the `is_a()` method. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

Comment: This has been answered before. You can use `is_subclass_of()` Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782653/checking-if-a-class-is-instance-of-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer: [PHP get overridden methods from child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669046/php-get-overridden-methods-from-child-class)

You can use `Reflectionclass` 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

Answer (score 6):

```
$b = new B();

$b_extends_a = is_subclass_of($b, "A"); //Returns true
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php

Comment: This checks a class ... which is fine. But I want to see if a method in that class belongs to a parent class or not... such as `method` in this case.

Comment: `u54r` answered your question, so I think I don't need to update my answer anymore.